camera app problem
I installed ubuntu 24.04 , in the launcher there is icon for camera app but when I open it I get message that there is no camera detected , I downloaded cheese app and it detected the camera so I decided to remove camera app and when I searched for camera app in software store it asks me to install it so camera app is not installed but there is an icon in the launcher and I dont know how to remove this icon , finally I installed camera app and another camera icon appeared and this time after installing it worked but still dont know how to get rid of that extra camera icon in the launcher.

This is very confusing. Please describe what problem you are having, add a screenshot, and also describe what you have tried, step by step

I have "camera app " icon among other apps when I open "show apps" but the app is not installed , just an icon and trying to delete this icon

The new camera app is installed as APT, but the app store only shows Snap apps.
To remove the camera app, open a terminal and enter the command sudo apt remove gnome-snapshot.
If you want a GUI app store for APT apps, then install gnome-software with sudo apt install gnome-software, and you don't anymore have to use the command line to install/remove software.

It worked , thank you Sir.

You can accept my answer if it works.

I just did it but by mistake clicked on down arrow once, click on up arrow few times , thanks again

I am referring to accepting the answer by clicking the checkmark (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

For the camera to be found, the user needs to be a member of the video group. This can be resolved by running following on command line:
sudo usermod -aG video $USER
Logging out and back in again is required for the change to take effect.
The configuration error appears to be an Ubuntu bug.
I obtained the info from:
https://itsfoss.com/no-camera-found-ubuntu/
I had the same problem and this solution worked for me.
